# html5 video on chrome mobile - native player control bar missing icon ( options )

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, http-live-streaming

env - mobile Chrome Beta (68.0.3440.23)

to the above serve html5 video.src with :

Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl

body of m3u8 that you see in devtools.network screenshot below

Playback is OK. However, as shown in screenshot, the native player control bar is missing the  'options' icon normally seen in lower right , just to the right of the fullscreen icon.

Issue - not able to figure out why native player decides not to include the options icon. I need options because i want to be able to 'caste' the playback to a TV with a chromecast.

Note on the content of the m3u8 shown in attachement . It is created on the server ( not a static m3u8 ).  When static m3u8's are played, the control bar DOES CONTAIN the options icon.

But i do not see the error in the m3u8 thats being sent in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: chrome mobile v 67 will display both the options and option.caste icons. But the sample hls m3u8's dont actually play on the TV receiver. The tv starts a load on the https ... m3u8 , flashing the url being loaded along with the onLoading spinner... but playback never starts and it reverts to the caste landing page on TV. Not able to debug it on the receiver.

Comment: still a fluid env if you want to avoid CC sender /receiver libs and to just have html5 video.src tag value tell the native player what to load, hoping you get control bar in the native player that includes options menu that will open 'cast to ' dialog and selectionList for CC devices. AsOf chrome 72, by changing ALL urls to end in /default.m3u8  i was able to get it to work on Chrome mobile devices. The native player appears to key off file extension in the url rather than inspect http.hdr.content-type.  IMO - the filetype in url was key to resolving Html5 player and getting cast to work .

Answer (score 1):

Unless something has recently changed (which is of course very possible...), mobile Chrome does not support casting from the browser for videos.

You can see this in some Google Chromecst online info, for example, if you switch between the 'Computer' and 'Android' Tab at this link:

- https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3228332?hl=en&ref_topic=4602553&visit_id=0-636651854499397401-528434718&rd=1&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1

It may be that the option bar appears for static m3u8 because the player allows seeking with that format but not with dynamic m3u8s - i.e. the option bar may still not include the ability to CAST.

Comment: thank you. i think its a fluid situation. Recently, m3u8 in general would cast - https://bitmovin.com/mpeg-dash-hls-examples-sample-streams/ .  these all worked but no longer work!  Now,  the cast button still displays under options and it appears to start a stream to the TV but does not play. I guess i could debug it at 9222 for details. static m3u8 still cast fine.  Everything works fine static, dynamic on ios and to apple TV. I thought i could finesse ios vs android with m3u8 for either individual play and or queuing up lists.   Not a great choice i guess.